# how to access variable value from method of one class from another class using symfony

Tags: php, symfony

I am new to symfony framework. I have a value of variable from one method of class. I need to access the value from another class method. Can anyone help me to do that using symfony. Thanks in advance

```
class A():
   method a():
      s = 10;

class B():
   method b():
      ----
```

I need to access the value of s from method b using symfony.

Comment: put some code here - what do you want to achieve exactly

Answer (score 1):

This is not specific to `Symfony` in any kind (not event `php` specific, this is just `OOP` basics).

Answering your question (in very general way).

One of possible solutions is that uou can make `$s` variable a public field of class `A`:

```
class A
{
    public $s;
    public function a()
    {
        $this->s = 10;
    }
}

class B
{
    public function b()
    {
        $a = new A();
        $a->a(); //you need this to set value, maybe this should be in constructor?
        $s = $a->s; // this will give you your $s value (10)
    }

}
```